# How does one use math operators in xy-pic?

Tags: positioning, xy-pic, math-operators

I am trying to format some large commutative diagrams (using the `\xymatrix` command) that involve colimits, and I would like to have the indexing information for the colimits appear underneath the word "colim" rather than as a subscript of "colim" (to save space).

I have a command `$\DeclareMathOperator*{\mocolim}{colim}$` which solves this problem for ordinary displayed equations (inside the equation environment, say).  In other words, the command
`$\begin{equation} \mocolim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n) \end{equation}$`  puts the symbols `$n\rightarrow \infty$` underneath the word colim.

However, if I use the same command inside `\xymatrix`, the subscript `$n\rightarrow \infty$` is displayed as a subscript, down and to the right of the word colim (just as would happen in ordinary mathmode).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entries in `\xymatrix` are typeset in `\textstyle` mode, so the "solution" would be to say

```
\mocolim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}
```

but this may have adverse effects on vertical alignment of entries.